# Laravel 5.4 - Prefixing and applying two middlewares for a multi-tenant application's routes

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, middleware

I'd like to group `/account/{account_id}` as well as protect every route inside it with the `auth` middleware and a middleware that will check if the logged user has access to this account. Unfortunately it's not working.

Here is my code

#### web.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'account/{account}', 'middleware' => 'userHasPermissionForAccount'], function() {
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'posts'], function () {
            Route::get('{post}', 'PostsController@index')->where([
                'post' => '\d+'
            ]);
        });
        // more routes here...
    });
});
```

#### app/http/kernel.php

```
// ...
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    // ...
    'userHasPermissionForAccount' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserCanAccessContent::class,
];
```

It don't even triggers the code inside my custom middleware and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I would use policies (gates), since you can use policy as middleware.

```
$ php artisan make:policy AcccountPolicy
```

Register the policy in **AuthServiceProvider**:

```
/**
 * The policy mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $policies = [
    Account::class => AccountPolicy::class, //Account is model, remember to import!
];
```

Inside policy file (**app/policies/AccountPolicy.php**), create method lets say "manage"

```
/**
 * Determine if ....
 *
 * @param  \App\User  $current
 * @param  \App\Account  $account
 * @return bool
 */
public function manage(User $current, Account $account)
{
    //return some logic here to check if $current is part of $account
}
```

And then use this policy as middleware:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'account/{account}', 'middleware' => 'can:manage,account'], function...
```